# List all files recursively in a given Directory except files in hidden folders

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following piece of code:

```
Files.find( startPath, Integer.MAX_VALUE, ( path, attributes ) -> path.toFile().isFile() )
            .map( p -> startPath.relativize( p ).toString() ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Which will return a List of file names with relative path inside a given path.
I am somehow stucked at additoinally excluding all the files which are placed in hidden folders somewhere along the file structure. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can filter the stream to check if the file is hidden?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov this is not working since it will just ignore hidden files, what i want is to ignore files which are in hidden directories

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Files.walkFileTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-) instead of Files.find:

```
List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();

Files.walkFileTree(startPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                                     BasicFileAttributes attr)
    throws IOException {
        if (attr.isRegularFile()) {
            files.add(startPath.relativize(file).toString());
        }
        return super.visitFile(file, attr);
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                                             BasicFileAttributes attr)
    throws IOException {
        if (Files.isHidden(dir) ||
            (attr instanceof DosFileAttributes && 
                ((DosFileAttributes) attr).isHidden())) {

            return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
        }
        return super.preVisitDirectory(dir, attr);
    }
});
```

The code looks longer, but it’s no less efficient than Files.find.

(If you’re wondering why the specific handling of DosFileAttributes is in there, it’s because the [documentation for Files.isHidden](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isHidden-java.nio.file.Path-) states, “On Windows a file is considered hidden if it isn't a directory and the DOS `hidden` attribute is set.”)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Replace

```
Files.find( startPath, Integer.MAX_VALUE, ( path, attributes ) -> path.toFile().isFile() )
            .map( p -> startPath.relativize( p ).toString() ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

with

```
Files.find( startPath, Integer.MAX_VALUE, ( path, attributes ) -> path.toFile().isFile() ).filter(e -> !e.toFile().isHidden())
            .map( p -> startPath.relativize( p ).toString() ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```